# Out of memory errors occur with a high heap size but low allocated size. Why?

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory

I have a fairly memory intensive process that can cause the heap size to grow near its limits (like 24 in this case).

However, when that process ends, and the Allocated memory (as listed in the DDMS Heap tool and in a heap dump) is far far lower like 6 or 7.

Despite the Allocated memory being low, and there being a lot of free memory, the heap doesn't seem to come back down.

So even though it says there is plenty of memory available I can still get out of memory errors in this case.

So it begs a couple questions:

1. Even though the Allocated memory in the Heap tab of DDMS and the heap dumps themselves only show 7mb of memory as allocated is there hidden memory that is not mentioned that is not being garbage collected?  If so, how do I track this down?
2. It seems out of memory errors are based on heap size, not allocated memory size.  So is there a way to force the heap size to come back down when it doesn't need to be so high when the memory intensive process is over?

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An out of memory occurs when you are trying to use more memory than the maximum allowed heap size. Note however that Android's GC currently does not defragment the heap and it seems that's the issue you are running into. Your heap may have a lot of memory available, but fragmented in small chunks. If the VM cannot find a chunk big enough for the allocation are you trying to do, an OOME will happen.

Comment: Thanks Romain.  Is there any way to avoid this or make this memory more usable?  Any clues in the right direction and I can research the rest... hopefully ;)   Thanks again.

Comment: On second thought, your comment already gives me a lot to look into.  Thanks

Comment: littleFluffyKitty how you got solved this issue out of memory due to heap size incresing.i am getting the same issue but unable to solve.can you help me?

Comment: @nikki and Ersin, I haven't found a "fix" outside of using less memory, and reusing and recycling objects where possible and beneficial. The other major piece is if you are working with Bitmaps, on older versions of Android (before Honeycomb) their memory is stored in the native heap and has some special considerations. There are a lot of good answers here on StackOverflow related to "Bitmap Memory" and "Bitmap Recylcing" that might be helpful as well.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty thanks for your answer.But now i got solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried popping in a System.gc() ?

If you're working with bitmaps, you might want to look at this: http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/scarce-commodities-google-android-memory-and-bitmaps/

Comment: Does System.gc() do anything more than the normal automatic garbage collection?  Thanks for the link I'll take a look at it.  I'm doing very little with bitmaps in this case, so I think it is something else.

Comment: Actually doesn't force the "automatic" collection to occur... Just "say" to the System that it's a good time to 'look' and when it's possible call the GC. (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#gc())

Answer (score -2):

For Android 3.2 (API 13) and up, it may help to add **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"** to your manifest if you have large bitmaps that need "match_parent" from layout-port and layout-land xml files.