# How to prevent OutofMemoryError when building up a long list of string in android

Tags: android

we get the following error in our app:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:153)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:217)
```

And we believe this is due to:
[Out of memory errors occur with a high heap size but low allocated size. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761547/out-of-memory-errors-occur-with-a-high-heap-size-but-low-allocated-size-why)

Is there a way to defragment the memory?

How do we prevent this from happening? Our idea was to slice the big StringBuilder into multiple instance and create new instances for when we have reached a maximum length we have specified? Is this going to work?

Comment: How many instances of StringBuilder are you creating and using? Maybe try limiting it to one and carefully calling gc()?