# Out of memory error when calling web api using volley in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I made general Class called `BaseActivity.java` and in that I define volley function. Also I extends `BaseActivity` class to each activity and use method to call web api. 
Code is given bellow.

```
    public void callVolley(final Context cContext, String mMethodType, final String mMethodname, String URL,
                       final HashMap<String, String> mMap, int initialTimeoutMs, boolean shouldCache, int maxNumRetries,
                       Boolean isProgressDailogEnable, Boolean isCancelable, final Activity aActivity) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mMap.put("deviceType", "1");
    SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREFRENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    mMap.put("loginUserId", setting.getString("userId", "") + "");
    mMap.put("deviceToken", "" + setting.getString("deviceToken", ""));
    mMap.put("deviceId", setting.getString("deviceId", "") + "");

    if (Constant.d) Log.i(mMethodname + "==>", mMap.toString() + "");
    if (!isOnline(cContext)) {
        showErrorDailog(aActivity, Constant.PleaseCheckInternetConnection, R.drawable.icon);
    } else {
        StringRequest jsObjRequest;
        int reqType = 0;
        String RequestURL = URL.trim();
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(cContext);

        if (isProgressDailogEnable) {
            customLoaderDialog = new CustomLoaderDialog(cContext);
            customLoaderDialog.show(isCancelable);

            customLoaderDialog.dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    //  finish();
                }
            });
        }
        if (mMethodType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("GET"))
            reqType = com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET;
        else if (mMethodType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("POST"))
            reqType = com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST;

        if (RequestURL.equals(""))
            RequestURL = Constant.WEBSERVICE_URL;
        else
            RequestURL = URL;

        if (Constant.d) Log.d("reqType", reqType + "");
        jsObjRequest = new StringRequest(reqType, RequestURL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (Constant.d) Log.d("response==>" + mMethodname, "" + response);
                if (customLoaderDialog != null) {
                    try {
                        customLoaderDialog.hide();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {
                    IVolleyRespose iVolleyRespose = (IVolleyRespose) aActivity;
                    iVolleyRespose.onVolleyResponse(RESPONSE_ERROR, response, mMethodname);
                } else {

                    JSONObject json_str;
                    try {
                        json_str = new JSONObject(response);
                        int status = json_str.getInt("status");

                        if (status == 101) {

                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(aActivity).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle(Constant.Alert_Name);
                            alertDialog.setMessage(json_str.getString("message") + "");
                            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                            SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREFRENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                            setting.edit().clear().commit();
                                            ExitActivity.exitApplication(aActivity);
                                            finish();
                                            System.exit(0);
                                        }
                                    });
                            alertDialog.show();
                        } else {
                            IVolleyRespose iVolleyRespose = (IVolleyRespose) aActivity;
                            iVolleyRespose.onVolleyResponse(RESPONSE_OK, response, mMethodname);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                IVolleyRespose iVolleyError = (IVolleyRespose) aActivity;
                iVolleyError.onVolleyError(RESPONSE_ERROR, "Error", mMethodname);

                if (customLoaderDialog != null) {
                    customLoaderDialog.hide();
                }

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                String strRequest = "";
                try {
                    strRequest = getWebservicejsObjRequestforvolley(mMethodname, mMap);
                    if (Constant.d) Log.d("Request==>", strRequest + "");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("json", strRequest);

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        //if(Constant.d) Log.d("Request==>", jsObjRequest+"");
        jsObjRequest.setTag(mMethodname);
        jsObjRequest.setShouldCache(shouldCache);

        jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(initialTimeoutMs, maxNumRetries, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }
}
```

Above is the code which I used and it gives some time `OutOfMemoryError` exceptoin
Crash Log is given bellow:

```
0   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: thread creation failed
1   at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
2   at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1050)
3   at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:142)
4   at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:67)
5   at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:79)
6   at com.truepal.truepalapp.activity.BaseActivity.callVolley(BaseActivity.java:211)
7   at com.truepal.truepalapp.activity.QuestionActivity.callforAnswerList(QuestionActivity.java:875)
8   at com.truepal.truepalapp.activity.QuestionActivity.onResume(QuestionActivity.java:487)
9   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1157)
10  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
11  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
12  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
13  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1998)
14  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
15  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
16  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
17  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
18  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
19  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
20  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
21  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
22  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
23  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Issue is I cannot found why this error occur Randomly when I use application for 5 to 10 min.
If any one face this type of error then solution is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029101/android-volley-give-me-an-outofmemory-exception

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/volley-users/pDBxx-r-YG0

Comment: why are you creating a requestqueue everytime just make it one time and reuse it

Comment: Analyse your dumps, what is leaking?

Comment: @ankitagrawal: This code is in base class. and I extend it in each activity so per each activity I make requestqueue passing context of that activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary solution but not recommended.

Add this line in Manifest file

```
<application
     android:largeHeap="true"
```

OR

also check these link
[Android Volley give me an outOfMemory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029101/android-volley-give-me-an-outofmemory-exception)

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Answer (score 0):

Add largeheap property to application tag in manifest file as below :

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```