# Volley OutOfMemoryError even after using single instance

Tags: android, android-volley

I make repeated requests using a `Timer`. I get `OutOfMemoryError` after a while. I extend Application class to get a single instance. But I still get the error and app crashes. It works again after I clear the cache.

I programmatically clear the cache every few seconds, but when I do that I get `NegativeArraySizeException`. Am I doing the single instance thing wrong.

```
   public ArrayList getCo_ordinates(String deviceId) {
        String URL_CO_ORDINATES = "http://192.168.1.42:8080/image/getDevicePosition?deviceId=" + deviceId;
            myApplication.getRequestQueue().start();

        final JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_CO_ORDINATES, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                try {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        X = response.getJSONObject(i).getString("xCoordinate");
                        Y = response.getJSONObject(i).getString("yCoodinate");
                        System.out.println("xCoordinate" + X);
                        System.out.println("yCoodinate" + Y);
                    if(isCoordinateDifferent()) {
                        addTap(Integer.parseInt(X), Integer.parseInt(Y));
                    }else {
                    }
                    updateNewCoordinates(Integer.parseInt(X),Integer.parseInt(Y));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could Not connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String deviceID = Build.SERIAL;
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                return params;
            }
        };
        myApplication.addToRequestQueue(request);
    return null;
}
```

The application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private int cacheClearCount=0;
private static MyApplication myApplication;
private int installCount = 0;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myApplication = this;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
}

public MyApplication(){

}

public int getCacheClearCount() {
    return cacheClearCount;

}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    return requestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request, String tag) {
    getRequestQueue().add(request);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request) {
    getRequestQueue().add(request);
}

public void cancelPendingRequest(Object tag) {
    getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag);
}

public void setCacheClearCount(int cacheClearCount) {
    this.cacheClearCount = cacheClearCount;
}

public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return myApplication;
}
```

Comment: try this answers...... http://stackoverflow.com/a/17679457/3678308

Comment: @ExceptionLover..the error occurs because I send repeated requests..i think the link's for bitmap error

Comment: may be you are right...!!!

Comment: @ExceptionLover. thanks  a lot for trying to help

Comment: problem is solved???

Comment: Post your log both OutOfMemoryError & NegativeArraySizeException so it will help to know initial node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because you're repeatedly creating new `String`s. Use `StringBuffer` instead.